# How can I get values from two Laravel tables using loop on my view

Tags: php, laravel

The below line returns all record from two tables, because I added a relationship for these two tables.

```
$allmarketers =  ProductStock::whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?',[$currentMonth])->get();
```

Now I want to loop through the records in the view and display the records from two tables for each user. I forgot how to achieve this.

I tried

```
@foreach($allmarketers as $item)
```

But how can I get the values of both tables inside this loop?

Var_dump

```
n)#601 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(3) { [0]=> object(App\ProductStock)#602 (26) { ["table":protected]=> string(14) "product_stocks" ["fillable":protected]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(8) "marketer" [1]=> string(6) "target" [2]=> string(6) "_token" [3]=> string(10) "updated_at" [4]=> string(10) "created_at" } ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> int(97) ["user_id"]=> int(70) ["marketer"]=> string(18) "Samson Samson | 70" ["target"]=> string(3) "100" ["_token"]=> NULL ["status"]=> int(1) ["vehicle"]=> string(10) "Unassigned" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2020-01-07 13:11:47" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2020-01-07 13:11:47" } ["original":protected]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> int(97) ["user_id"]=> int(70) ["marketer"]=> string(18) "Samson Samson | 70" ["target"]=> string(3) "100" ["_token"]=> NULL ["status"]=> int(1) ["vehicle"]=> string(10) "Unassigned" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2020-01-07 13:11:47" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2020-01-07 13:11:47" } ["changes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } } [1]=> object(App\ProductStock)#603 (26) { ["table":protected]=> string(14) "product_stocks" ["fillable":protected]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(8) "marketer" [1]=> string(6) "target" [2]=> string(6) "_token" [3]=> string(10) "updated_at" [4]=> string(10) "created_at" } ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> int(98) ["user_id"]=> int(72) ["marketer"]=> string(22) "Emmanuel Increase | 72" ["target"]=> string(3) "150" ["_token"]=> NULL ["status"]=> int(1) ["vehicle"]=> string(10) "Unassigned" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2020-01-07 13:11:47" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2020-01-07 13:11:47" } ["original":protected]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> int(98) ["user_id"]=> int(72) ["marketer"]=> string(22) "Emmanuel Increase | 72" ["target"]=> string(3) "150" ["_token"]=> NULL ["status"]=> int(1) ["vehicle"]=> string(10) "Unassigned" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2020-01-07 13:11:47" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2020-01-07 13:11:47" } ["changes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } } [2]=> object(App\ProductStock)#604 (26) { ["table":protected]=> string(14) "product_stocks" ["fillable":protected]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(8) "marketer" [1]=> string(6) "target" [2]=> string(6) "_token" [3]=> string(10) "updated_at" [4]=> string(10) "created_at" } ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> int(99) ["user_id"]=> int(73) ["marketer"]=> string(18) "Timothy Kukah | 73" ["target"]=> string(3) "200" ["_token"]=> NULL ["status"]=> int(1) ["vehicle"]=> string(10) "Unassigned" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2020-01-07 13:11:47" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2020-01-07 13:11:47" } ["original":protected]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> int(99) ["user_id"]=> int(73) ["marketer"]=> string(18) "Timothy Kukah | 73" ["target"]=> string(3) "200" ["_token"]=> NULL ["status"]=> int(1) ["vehicle"]=> string(10) "Unassigned" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2020-01-07 13:11:47" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2020-01-07 13:11:47" } ["changes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } } } }
```

Comment: Could you provide var_dump($allmarketers) here?

Comment: okay one second

Comment: check the question..i edited it with the var_dump

Comment: Please can you show the relationship you set up and also how one of the tables relates to a user as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this below. hope it might help you. it's a simple code. I presume you have id column in your DB.

```
<table class="table is-striped">
        @if(count($allmarketers) > 0)
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
          @endif
 <tbody>
 @foreach ($allmarketers as $item)
          <tr>
            <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->created_at}}</td>
          </tr>
 @endforeach
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i need the record of the second table

Comment: if you said that `$allmarketers` has relationship with both tables it should provide data from both tables.